# Playing VCDs on Ubuntu

Tags: 11.04, video-player, vcd

What can I play VCDs with? I tried MPlayer, but it ran the intro scene for a few seconds and exited (I've to choose from the menu in that scene). Does Totem/Movie Player support VCD and stuff?

**Update**

I was able to to get tracks using `mplayer vcd://` command. Nothing plays from the first track (`mplayer vcd://1`), video only appears on the second track.

On VLC I could play it normally from the GUI.

Is there anyway to play VCD on the default softwares (Media Player/Banshee)?

Comment: Can you clarify if you've installed any extra codecs e.g. sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras  sudo apt-get install w32-codecs

Comment: @fossfreedom, installed any and all restricted codecs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VLC should be able to play VCD. Command line: `/usr/bin/vlc vcd://` or from within VLC: media, open disc:

[image]

Try and find out if you get any errors while doing this command line. Maybe you need some extra codecs.

For i386 install codecs:

`sudo apt-get install w32codecs libdvdcss2`

For amd64 install codecs:

`sudo apt-get install w64codecs libdvdcss2`

(but these might already be installed on your system)

Comment: VLC works. Totem/Media Player possible?

Comment: OK. So it is definitly a totem issue and not codecs!

Comment: nope, I always install proprietary codecs.

Comment: @Oxwivi may sound stupid but all I find are ppl complaining about totem not playing vcd's :-X

Comment: I ain't complaining, I want it working, but forget it problem solved.