# How to play vcd?

Tags: vlc, vcd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Playing VCDs on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42660/playing-vcds-on-ubuntu)

For playing vcd in UBUNTU somebody proposed to use gxine. However gxine doesn't start. When trying to start it from terminal, the response is:

```
/usr/bin/gxine.real: error while loading shared libraries: 
libmozjs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

VLC doesnt work for me as when I choose the cd it cant read the MRL.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Open your VLC Player Go to Media---> Open Disc---> Select SVCD/VCD option